# Predictive animations of RecyclerView not running with setHasStableIds and notifyDatasetChanged

Tags: android, android-animation, android-recyclerview

I am using setHasStableIds in the adapter and calling whole notifyDatasetChanged instead of notifyItemXYZ for various reasons. I am getting simple animations since the setHasStableIds(true), but when removing item, the offscreen item which should slide in-screen now, just fades in. (Exactly as the case with turned off predictive animations in Chet Haase talk https://youtu.be/imsr8NrIAMs). When I am using notifyItemRemoved, it works (however my other code becomes very inconvenient)

**TLDR; is there a way to get predictive (not only simple) animations when using setHasStableIds & notifyDatasetChanged with RecyclerView? (other than using notifyItemRemoved)**

Answer (score 0):

Asked few years ago, but maybe it'll be helpful for someone searching for the way to do this.

You can override getExtraLayoutSpace method in your layout manager to return, for example, at least average item size in pixels (to hide non-predictive animations off screen).

```
rv.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(rv.getContext()) {
        @Override
        protected int getExtraLayoutSpace(RecyclerView.State state) {
            return Math.max(averageItemSizePx, super.getExtraLayoutSpace(state));
        }
});
```

Of course, it has a performance cost, so be careful.

But sometimes this approach gives you non predictable animations - it depends on last scroll direction (from LinearLayoutManager sources)